# What is the difference between these 2 lines of Jquery? [Element Selection]

Tags: jquery, comparison, selector

my jquery code currently looks like this, using the element ID selector and setting the value to an empty string.

```
$("#theAddress").val("");
```

But I have since seen it done like the below example, I am struggling to understand what the difference is between the below and my line, why would you write it like the below, are there any benefits?

```
$("textarea[name=theAddress]").val("");
```

Thank You

Comment: You can try multiple type of selector to do the same job. It's up-to-you.

Comment: the first is selecting by id, the second is selecting by the tag's name and `name` attribute, they are not the same.

Comment: So just to be clear, there is no actual difference in terms of performance or optimization that I am missing? Is selecting by tag name and name attribute considered better than selecting by ID? is it more robust for example.

Comment: selecting by id will be faster than selecting by tag name and attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#theAddress")` selects the DOM element with an **id** of **theAddress** e.g. `<div id='theAddress'>..</div>`

`$("textarea[name=theAddress]")` selects a DOM element that is a `textarea` but specific that has the **name** attribute set to **theAddress** e.g. `<textarea name='theAddress'>...</textarea>`.

In both cases, you are setting the `value` to empty string.
This could conceivably select the same node if you have this element:

`<textarea id='theAddress' name='theAddress'>...</textarea>`

There isn't any real world benefits either way - it all depends on what you want to select.  Potentially the `#theAddress` approach may be marginally faster and should be unique (e.g. 0 or 1 results) as ids should be unique.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!